# Jest manual mock not working when using ES6 import

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

I can't use Jest with ES6 but it works for me in CommonJS.

If I use standard CommonJS `require` I can use Manual Mocking with Jest so this directory is seen `__mocks__` but ES6 is not working.

Here is the file structure:

```
-root
--src
---currency.js
---currency.test.js
---utils
----fetch-data.js
----__mocks__
-----fetch-data.js
```

The external REST API is in the `utils/fetch-data.js` so I am trying to mock this file in my `currency.test.js`. If I use CommonJS it works and here is the code set for it

```
// /utils/fetch.data.js

const axios = require("./axios");
// import axios from "./axios"; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS


const fetchData = async () => {
    const rates = await axios.get('https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest')
    return rates
}
 module.exports = fetchData;
//export default fetchData; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS
```

the mocking test in `__mocks__`

```
// utils/__mocks__/fetch-data.js
const fetchData = jest.fn(() => {
    Promise.resolve({
        status: "MOCK",
        data: {}
    })
});

module.exports = fetchData;
// export default fetchData; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS
```

then inside the currency file

```
// currency.js

// import fetchData from "./utils/fetch-data"; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS
const fetchData = require("./utils/fetch-data");

module.exports = class CurrencyComparison {
// export default class CurrencyComparison { // <- ES6 export when I want to try use ES6 I flip this on and comment the module.exports which is CommonJS

  constructor(salary) {
    this.salary = salary
  }
  fetchCurrentExchange = async () => { // <-- we are testing this as fetchData is from an API
    return await fetchData().then(res => {
      return [res.data.rates, res.status]
    })
  }
}
```

And now the test

```
// currency.test.js

// import CurrencyComparison from "./currency_comparison"; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS
const CurrencyComparison = require("./currency_comparison");

// Task 10: Import and mock fetchData
const fetchData = require("./utils/fetch-data.js");
// import fetchData from "./utils/fetch-data.js"; // <-- when I try ES6 I flip this on and comment over the CommonJS

jest.mock("./utils/fetch-data.js"); // not performing properly with ES6

const testSalary = new CurrencyComparison(50000);

it("Receives current currency exchange data", async ()=>{
  //arrange
  const mockResponse = {
    status : "Mock",
    data: {
      "base": "USD",
      "rates": {
        "CCD": 50,
      },
      "date": "2021-05-17"
    }
  }
  const expectedValue = [{"CCD": 50}, "Mock"];

  // Mock the resolved value of fetchData
  fetchData.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResponse); // it fails here giving the clue that the __mocks__ folder is not used as the mocking with ES6. the test works with CommonJS

  
  //act
  const actualValue = await testSalary.fetchCurrentExchange() 
  
  //assert
  expect(actualValue).toEqual(expectedValue);
});
```

Here is how I have set up package.json only qouting the most relevant codes!

```
// package.json

  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.7",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {}
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
```

I have a `.babelrc` as well

```
// .babelrc
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I don't have `jest.config.js` and `babel.config.js`

Test results from ES6 (ignore other test)

```
 FAIL  src/currency.test.js
  the entire block of tests                                                                                                                                                          
    √ Gets conversion rate for currency (4 ms)
    √ Converts USD salary to hourly CAD pay (1 ms)                                                                                                                                   
    √ Respond with different salaries based on currency (2 ms)                                                                                                                       
    × Receives current currency exchange data (1 ms)                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                     
  ● the entire block of tests › Receives current currency exchange data                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                     
    TypeError: fetchData.mockResolvedValueOnce is not a function

      84 |
      85 |     // Mock the resolved value of fetchData
    > 86 |     fetchData.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResponse);
         |               ^
      87 |
      88 |
      89 |     //act

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/currency_comparison.test.js:86:15)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total                                                                                                                                             
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.563 s
Ran all test suites.
```

And here is the test result the same code but with CommonJS

```
 PASS  src/currency.test.js
  the entire block of tests
    √ Gets conversion rate for currency (2 ms)                                                                                                                                       
    √ Converts USD salary to hourly CAD pay                                                                                                                                          
    √ Respond with different salaries based on currency (1 ms)                                                                                                                       
    √ Receives current currency exchange data (1 ms)                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                     
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total                                                                                                                                                       
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.596 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

What am I doing wrong for Manual Mocking to not work with ES6 but works with the standard CommonJS. What am I missing in my configuration files etc.?

Answer (score -1):

Should have gone to ChatGPT here is the answer in case someone wants it.

> To configure Jest to work with ES6 (ECMAScript 2015 and later), you
> need to ensure that Jest can understand and transpile your ES6 code
> during testing. Here are the steps to configure Jest for ES6:
>
> 1. Install Required Packages:
>
>    Make sure you have the necessary packages installed. You'll need `babel-jest` to enable Jest to use Babel for transpilation.
>
>    ```bash
>    npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
>    ```
> 2. Create a Babel Configuration File:
>
>    Create a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project with the following content:
>
>    ```
>    {
>      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
>    }
>    ```
>
>    This configuration tells Babel to use the `@babel/preset-env` preset, which automatically determines the Babel plugins needed based
>    on your target environment.
> 3. Update Jest Configuration:
>
>    Update your Jest configuration in your `package.json` or create a separate `jest.config.js` file. Ensure that the transform option
>    includes the `babel-jest` transformer.
>
>    If using `package.json`:
>
>    ```json
>    {
>      "scripts": {
>        "test": "jest"
>      },
>      "jest": {
>        "transform": {
>          "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
>        }
>      }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    If using `jest.config.js`:
>
>    ```js
>    module.exports = {
>      transform: {
>        '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
>      }
>    };
>    ```
> 4. Configure Babel for Jest:
>
>    Make sure that Babel is configured to use the preset in the `babel.config.js` file:
>
>    ```js
>    module.exports = {
>      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
>    };
>    ```
>
>    If you're using `.babelrc` instead of `babel.config.js`, ensure that the `babel-jest` transformer is configured to use it.
> 5. Run Jest Tests:
>
>    With these configurations in place, you should be able to run your Jest tests using the following command:
>
>    ```bash
>    npm test
>    ```
>
>    Jest should now transpile your ES6 code using Babel during the testing process. Adjust the configurations according to your project
>    structure and requirements.

All the test results are working with ES6 now:

```
> jest

 PASS  src/currency.test.js
  the entire block of tests
    √ Gets conversion rate for currency (3 ms)                                                                                                                                       
    √ Converts USD salary to hourly CAD pay                                                                                                                                          
    √ Respond with different salaries based on currency (2 ms)                                                                                                                       
    √ Receives current currency exchange data (2 ms)                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                     
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total                                                                                                                                                       
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.63 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: So you basically gave up on running tests against es modules.